# How to put excel charts on C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, excel-charts

By using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, I can create the excel chart on my C# program and extract to excel file.

But I want to directly put the chart to C# wpf.

If it's not possible, can anyone suggest a simple charting library/dll for me.

Comment: You can either embed Excels ActiveX control or if you want a pure .NET solution check out the [Chart class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart(v=vs.110).aspx).  However the latter is WinForms so you'll need to host it in a WinForm container in WPF

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use chart in wpf, you can import DataVisualization.Toolkit and use the chart control